# Need help in understanding MR data processing for small data sets using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Need help in understanding MR data processing for small data sets using Hadoop.

Please consider the following hypothetical scenario:

```
1) Input Data to be processed : 100 MB
2) Block Size : 64 MB
3) Replication Factor : 2
4) Cluster Size : 2 (Data Node 1 and Data Node 2)
```

The data in Data Node 1 will be split as 64MB + 36MB(total 100MB of Input Data)
The replicated data will be available in Data Node 2 as well (64 MB + 36 MB)

Question:

Please help in understanding how will the 64 MB and 36 MB data be processed? 
Will entire data be processed only from DataNode1. DataNode2 will just be used for backup in case if DataNode1 goes down?

OR

Will DataNode2 also be used for processing the data?
Please let me know if more explanation is required on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will use both the datanodes. So number of mappers will always be equal to number of splits (unless you restrict it using properties or driver code). See [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have a gzipped file as an input, then regardless it have 2 blocks it would be entirely processed by a single mapper on a single node. If you are running YARN NM on both of the datanodes, they have enough memory to start 2 mapper tasks and the cluster is quiet (no other tasks are running), then most likely both mappers would be started on the same node.